# Laravel Connection could not be established with host mail.veebimajutus.ee [Operation not permitted #1]

Tags: laravel, email, web

When i am testing on localhost, it works, but on live server it won't.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.veebimajutus.ee
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=password-recovery@domain.ee
MAIL_PASSWORD=pass123
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

It says this:

```
Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host mail.veebimajutus.ee [Operation not permitted #1]
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Does you live server block smtp requests?

Comment: Yes, thanks! I asked them about this and they said that smtp is not allowed.